# C# Remoting (legacy) from nunit tests causes Security exception

Tags: c#, nunit, remoting

I am writing system wide tests for legacy api that uses remoting. Remoting is working if i call it from example: console application.

However following code from NUnit project:

```
((FooBar)System.Activator.GetObject(typeof (FooBar), "http://localhost/FooBar.rem")).SomeMethod("abc");
```

Fails with exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException : Type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the types derived from it (such as System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are not permitted to be deserialized at this security level.
```

Many pointers for this exception shows changes on server side security settings, however because server works with other consumer it seems that security issue is on client side.

I have tried add:

```
        var clientProvider = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
        IDictionary props = new Hashtable();

        const int httpConnectionLimit = 100;
        const int httpTimeout = 30*1000;

        props["clientConnectionLimit"] = httpConnectionLimit;
        props["timeout"] = httpTimeout;

        var channel = new HttpChannel(props, clientProvider, null);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
```

No effect.

Runner is Resharper 9. Tried MS runner too but seems to fail with same error.

Sadly, at this point of refactoring old system to use modern technologies like rest to communication isn't an option.

Tested with Nunit 2.6.3 and 2.6.4. 2.6.2 had one issue which looked like this but it seems this isn't same.

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking port 80 on your machine?

Comment: Actually localhost is just examle, system under test resides on another server. From very same computer i can connect and use remotes from console application so ports are not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Underlaying issue is following, this this is NUnit bug.

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/522

Comment: Note that the NUnit team closed the item as Not A Bug.  Comments on the bug ticket show a workaround where the client provider needs the TypeFilterLevel set to Full.